# No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/

Tags: android-fragment, android, rss

Приложение работает до тех пор, пока я не кликаю второй раз подряд по item. Появляется эта ошибка: No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/ 
По идее, оно должно просто обновить список новостей, но оно падает.Что может быть?

В манифесте прописано:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

и

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Переход из listview:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fTrans.replace(R.id.framelayout1, frag1);
        break;
    case 1:
        fTrans.replace(R.id.framelayout1, frag2);
        break;
    case 2:
        fTrans.replace(R.id.framelayout1, frag3);
        break;
    case 3:
        fTrans.replace(R.id.framelayout1, frag4);
        break;
    case 4:
        fTrans.replace(R.id.framelayout1, frag5);
        break;
    case 5:
        fTrans.replace(R.id.framelayout1, frag6);
        break;
    case 6:
        fTrans.replace(R.id.framelayout1, frag7);

    default:
        break;
    }
    fTrans.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашла ошибку )))
Я не дописала строчку fTrans.addToBackStack(null); после все заработало как положено:

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fTrans.addToBackStack(null);
    switch (position)
```